# pip install channels_redis не устанавливается

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь установить `pip install channels_redis` и пытался `pip install channels-redis`
Я использую PyCharm
но я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pussy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-
install-_5s4hitb\\hiredis_60550b6fb3f345df9b6b2f7662721b7a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pussy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_5s4hitb\\hiredis_60550b6
fb3f345df9b6b2f7662721b7a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools impor
t setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Pussy
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gobfy7ts\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Pussy\AppData\R
oaming\Python\Python310\Include\hiredis'
         cwd: C:\Users\Pussy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_5s4hitb\hiredis_60550b6fb3f345df9b6b2f7662721b7a\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    C:\Users\Pussy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_5s4hitb\hiredis_60550b6fb3f345df9b6b2f7662721b7a\setup.py:7: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in fa
vour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import sys, imp, os, glob, io
    C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:697: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versi
ons. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
    copying hiredis\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
    copying hiredis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
    copying hiredis\hiredis.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
    copying hiredis\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\hiredis
    running build_ext
    building 'hiredis.hiredis' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
Pussy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_5s4hitb\\hiredis_60550b6fb3f345df9b6b2f7662721b7a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pussy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-
install-_5s4hitb\\hiredis_60550b6fb3f345df9b6b2f7662721b7a\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.St
ringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
 install --record 'C:\Users\Pussy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gobfy7ts\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-
headers 'C:\Users\Pussy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Include\hiredis' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Установите более старую версию Python

Comment: Там же в ошибке пишет: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Для сборки пакета нужен Visual C.